# Execute rest of the goals after successful backtracking

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I can't seem to find this particular construct in prolog. Consider three predicates a/2, b/2 and c/2, such that:-

```
a(M, N) :- b(M, N), c(M, N)
```

Now the actual dependance is not exactly AND between the predicates. What is desired is both b and c are evaluated when M is not bound and the evaluated M therefore is returned in both the cases. However here, M will be evaluated till the last, and only a single value will be returned.

My question is :-

- Is it possible to return a value in prolog?
- Since if b fails the whole thing fails. However is it possible to continue the execution, even after b fails?
- Is it possible to return a value selectively after b succeeds and after c succeeds?

Comment: Thanks. Was made in haste. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You always "return" a value in Prolog; this value is either success, of failure
- Yes, it is possible to "continue the execution"; however, this is not the most useful way of looking at it (see below)
- Yes, it is, but your question is not clear enough to answer the "how".

First things first: have you even tried to work your way through a textbook or a tutorial? It might help you to try and do this before moving on.

Then: in Prolog, you don't have an "AND" and "OR"; you have *conjunctions*, and *disjunctions*. To make it more confusing, neither the conjunction nor the disjunction has the same meaning as in logic or grammar. Instead:

`a, b` is closest to the *short-circuit evaluation* of the AND boolean operator in procedural languages: it means "`a`, and if it succeeds, `b`, and if it succeeds, `a, b` succeeds."

Then, the disjunction `( a ; b )` is **not like the short-circuited OR** of procedural languages. Instead, `( a ; b )` means "`a`, and if it succeeds, `( a ; b )` succeeds; then, `b`, and if if succeeds, `( a ; b )` succeeds again."

In Prolog, a disjunction like this:

```
foo(A) :-
    (   bar(A)
    ;   baz(A)
    ).
```

is equivalent to defining two separate clauses:

```
foo(A) :-
    bar(A).
foo(A) :-
    baz(A).
```

So here is a small program:

```
a(A) :- b(A), c(A).

b(x). b(y). b(z).
c(y).
```

**NB**: the capitalization is significant.

This program says: "`a(A)` will succeed if `b(A)` succeeds and then `c(A)` succeeds. `b(A)` succeeds if `A` can be unified with one of the atoms `x`, `y`, or `z`. `c(A)` succeeds if `A` can be unified with the atom `y`."

Try out how this behaves with the following queries:

```
?- a(A).
?- a(x).
?- a(y).
```

To see what is going on exactly, try:

```
?- trace(a/1), trace(b/1), trace(c/1).
```